# Commutative diagram of $R$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit. It is known that any sequence of $R$-module is exact if and only if the induced sequence at the localization by any maximal ideal of $R$ is exact. My question is if this property holds for commutative diagrams.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? Is the property you’re interested in: “A diagram of maps of $R$-modules is commutative iff its localization at any maximal ideal is commutative”? Or does it refer to exact diagrams of some kind?

Comment: Thats exactly what I am asking for: A diagram of maps of R-modules is commutative iff its localization at any maximal ideal is commutative?

Comment: Yes, that property is true. Indeed, the commutativity of the diagram is equivalent to a certain map being zero (the difference of the maps following two different paths). But said map is zero iff it is zero in every localization (a nice way to see it: $f: M \rightarrow N$ is zero iff $M \rightarrow N \rightarrow N$ is exact, where the morphisms are $f,id_N$).

Comment: Thank you very much @Mindlack it was easier than I thought